# buffer reading Audio Data from file giving zeros

Tags: java, android, file

In my application, I need to firstly read audio data from a specific file, and then store it in a buffer. After that i will use it for processing and stuff. The Problem is that when i try to print out its contents it give 0:

```
String data = String.valueOf(buffer[50]+"     "+buffer[100]+"     "+buffer[200]+buffer[599]);
display.setText(data);
```

Printing the above statment gives all zeros!... why???

Here is my code:

```
   public void readAudioDataFromFile() {

     String filePath2 = "/storage/sdcard0/Sounds/originalFile.pcm";
     FileInputStream ins = null;
     File file = new File(filePath2);
     int size = (int) file.length();    
     byte [] buffer=new byte [size];
     try {
       ins= new FileInputStream(filePath2);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
       ins.read(buffer, 0,size);
       int count =0;
       for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++)
       {
         if(buffer[i]!=0)
           count++;
       }
       String data = String.valueOf((count); 
       display.setText(data);
     } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
```

The weird thing is that when i tried the following statement:

```
  int x= ins.read(buffer, 0,size);
```

When i printed x, it gave out a number equal to the file size,

Also when i tried printing out "count" as you can see in my code, it also gave an output!

I mean shouldnt all that mean that buffer is not empty??? and why if it's not empty, why is it when i try to print out its elements it gives me zeros???

Comment: What sort of data is the "audio data"?

Comment: @bugy we can probably assume PCM as he's talking about audio data, and the file's extension is PCM.

Comment: Your call to `ins.read` returns an integer representing the number of bytes read from the file.  What value does it return?

Comment: Ok so it is PCM.  Is it possible that the String equivalent of a PCM data element is 0?  I suspect that that does not actually mean that the data is 0.

Comment: What is the value of count?  While I doubt the odds are that buffer[50] and buffer[100], etc are all 0 why not look at ALL the data?  In your little for loop where you increment count why don't you log the value of buffer[i] there and see what you have?

Answer (score 1):

It is not immediately obvious what the problem is, but it could be caused by this:

```
ins.read(buffer, 0,size);
```

You are ignoring the result of the `read` call, which will tell you how many bytes were actually read into the `buffer`.  It is incorrect to assume that you will read `size` bytes ... even if the file size is `size`.

The correct way to do this is to loop until you have read the entire file ... something like this:

```
       int pos = 0;
       while (pos < size) {
           pos += ins.read(buffer, pos, size - pos);
       }
```

---

As to why you are getting all zeros, I think the simplest (and most likely) explanation is that the file you are reading contains all zeros.